# jQuery .delegate() and .undelegate() is not working in chrome 56 and above versions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please let me know the alternate function for this..

```
$("#_body").undelegate('click').delegate(".class> a",'click',function(){
```

I want to toggle the portlet on live click.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try `on()` and `off()` like:

```
$("#_body").off('click').on(".class> a",'click',function(){
  // your code here
});
```

**Using jQuery on()**

In jQuery 1.7, on() method was introduced which is an effort to simplify and merge most event bindings functions into one unified consistent API. If you are interested to see how on() replaces the functionality of all these event methods, open the jQuery 1.7.1 source code (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7/src/event.js#L965) and you will find that bind(), live() and delegate() all point to the on() method.

Comment: Thanks, but even this is not working. The click is not responsive for live click, bind unbind and on and off functions. Is there is any other function?